# how to optimize load all categories with image

Tags: category, image, optimization

right now, I have two nested foreach to loop through all the category, and it's extremely slow (3-4s on my local server). I think the problem is i use ->LOAD() to get the image path for the child category. is there any other way of doing it? or I should just redesign the whole navigation ui? any suggestion?

```
$categories = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/category')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('id')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('url_key')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('url')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('level',2)
    ->addIsActiveFilter()
    ->addAttributeToSort('position');

foreach ($categories as $category): 
    $id = $category->getId();
    $children = $category->getChildrenCategories();
    $name = $category->getName();
    $url_path = $category->getUrl();        

    foreach ($children as $child):                                      
        $childId = $child->getId();
        $thisChild = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/category')->load($childId);
        $name = $thisChild->getName();
        $url_key = $thisChild->getUrlKey(); 
        $url_path = $child->getUrl();
        $img = $thisChild->getImageUrl();   
    endforeach;
endforeach;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25993727/158325

Answer (score 3):

I don't know whether this even works, but you can try to work with `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Tree`

This class should give you the possibility to traverse the tree, but after loading all the categories.